# Setting conditional CSS class in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a React component with the following list of `div` elements with `id` as key. Whenever this item is clicked, the value is set in `state` as `currentMail` using `switch` function. Now I'm trying to check which `div` element in the list is the selected one so that I can set a custom CSS class `selected` using `this.state.currentMail.id == this.props.itemId`. However this doesn't work. What's wrong with this code?Is there a way to use key attribute to check the same although it looks same as `itemId` attribute?

```
<div key={mail.id} itemId={mail.id} onClick={()=>this.switch(mail.id)} 
className={"items " + (this.state.currentMail.id === this.props.itemId ? 'selected' : '')}>

switch(id) {
  //data;
  let item = this.state.data.find(x => x.RID === id);
  this.setState({
     currentMail: item
  });
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to show some more code. What happens in `this.switch` and what is `this.props.itemId`?

Comment: @putvande: switch function just sets the currentMail item from data object using the id that's passed in the state. `this.props.itemId` is the itemId attribute i set in the div element using `itemId={mail.id}`. I'm not sure if that's the right way to access that element attribute.

Comment: Ok. Perhaps `this.props.itemId` isn't being passed? Or its not the same type as the other id?

Comment: `this.props.itemId` is not the same as `mail.id`. Are you sure `this.props.itemId` is a thing? Did you try logging out the values to see whether they actually contain something useful?

Comment: So that was just a try as I was thinking i can get the attribute value i set `itemId={mail.id}` to check against the current state `this.state.currentMail.id === this.props.itemId`. But it is not working.

Comment: Why don't you just compare `this.state.currentMail.id === mail.id`? Here's a working example https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KvEpnt-w9YWoPHWSOV6

Comment: Also, you cannot use `switch` as the name of a function because it is a reserved word in JavaScript.

Comment: @djfdev: Great that works! Please post this as an answer `this.state.currentMail.id === mail.id`